# best practice for using decorator for send notification in asp core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, design-patterns

i need to send notification by sms or by email and i write code for this by `Decorator Pattern` .

but i dont know i write currect or not becuse when i need to use mutiple way (email and sms ) it not work good .

see the code :

```
public abstract class Notification
{
    public abstract Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string from, string subject, string content, string userName, string password, MailboxAddress to, int port, string smtpServer);
    public abstract Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string lineNumber, string userApiKey, string phoneNumber, string message, string secrectKey);
}
```

i have tow method `Send` becuse the are have diffrent argument .

i implement `Notification` in this class :

```
 public class SendNotification : Notification
{
    public SendNotification()
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Send Email Notifiaction
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="from"></param>
    /// <param name="subject"></param>
    /// <param name="content"></param>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <param name="to"></param>
    /// <param name="port"></param>
    /// <param name="smtpServer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string from, string subject, string content, string userName, string password, MailboxAddress to, int port, string smtpServer)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            try
            {
                client.Connect(smtpServer, port, true);
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                client.Authenticate(userName, password);
                emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(from));
                emailMessage.To.Add(to);
                emailMessage.Subject = subject;
                emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Text) { Text = content };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return OperationResult<string>.BuildFailure(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return OperationResult<string>.BuildSuccessResult("Success Send Email");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Send Sms Function
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lineNumber"></param>
    /// <param name="userApiKey"></param>
    /// <param name="phoneNumber"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="secrectKey"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string lineNumber, string userApiKey, string phoneNumber, string message, string secrectKey)
    {
        var token = new Token().GetToken(userApiKey, secrectKey);

        var restVerificationCode = new RestVerificationCode()
        {
            Code = message,
            MobileNumber = phoneNumber
        };

        var restVerificationCodeRespone = new VerificationCode().Send(token, restVerificationCode);
        if (restVerificationCodeRespone.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return OperationResult<string>.BuildSuccessResult(restVerificationCodeRespone.Message);
        }
        return OperationResult<string>.BuildFailure(restVerificationCodeRespone.Message);
    }
}
```

now i create class `SendSms` and class `Send Email` :

Email :

```
 public class NotificationEmail : SendNotification
{
    private readonly Notification notification;

    public NotificationEmail(Notification notification) 
    {
        this.notification = notification;
    }

    public override Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string from, string subject, string content, string userName, string password, MailboxAddress to, int port, string smtpServer)
    {
        return base.Send(from, subject, content, userName, password, to, port, smtpServer);
    }
}
```

SMS :

```
 public class NotificationSms : SendNotification
{
    private readonly Notification notification;

    public NotificationSms(Notification notification) 
    {
        this.notification = notification;
    }

    public override Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string lineNumber, string userApiKey, string phoneNumber, string message, string secrectKey)
    {
        return base.Send(lineNumber, userApiKey, phoneNumber, message, secrectKey);
    }
}
```

now i use this code by this way in my class :

```
SendNotification notif = new SendNotification();
NotificationSms smsSend = new NotificationSms(notif);
NotificationEmail emailSend = new NotificationEmail(smsSend);
var sendSms = await smsSend.Send(smsSetting.Result.LineNumber, smsSetting.Result.userApikey, to, content, smsSetting.Result.secretKey);
var sendEmail = await emailSend.Send(emailSetting.Result.From, "Email Confirm Code", content, emailSetting.Result.Username, emailSetting.Result.Password, to, emailSetting.Result.Port, emailSetting.Result.SmtpServer);
```

**now i need to use the best practice for using the decorator . how can i improve my code and best design in decorator???**

Answer (score 1):

Why would you force yourself to use the decorator pattern and not just use the more appropriate strategy pattern or template method pattern.

Decorator pattern is for adding responsibility.. but you are not adding responsibility, you are decorating an object with its main functionality... do not use the decorator for that.

I'd advice using the strategy pattern

Some documentation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

TL:DR: using composition you construct an object using its appropriate behaviour. For you i'd say you need to have an interface that abstracts the send behaviour and have 2 implementations... for sms and email.
After having build that, simply compose the sendnotification object with either sms or email

Answer (score 0):

I would choose to separate the configuration from the actual message and have that be a dependency for the actual sending implementation. Separating it from the actual message allows you to create a simple interface that can be used for a variety of channels.

The decorator isn't really necessary unless you want to add some kind of behavior to the actual call.

```
public interface INotification
{
    Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string subject, string message);
}

public class SmsNotfication : INotification
{
    public SmsNotfication(string lineNumber, string userApiKey, string phoneNumber, string secrectKey)
    {

    }

    public Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string subject, string message);
    {
        var token = new Token().GetToken(userApiKey, secrectKey);

        var restVerificationCode = new RestVerificationCode()
        {
            Code = message,
            MobileNumber = phoneNumber
        };

        var restVerificationCodeRespone = new VerificationCode().Send(token, restVerificationCode);
        if (restVerificationCodeRespone.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return OperationResult<string>.BuildSuccessResult(restVerificationCodeRespone.Message);
        }
        return OperationResult<string>.BuildFailure(restVerificationCodeRespone.Message);
    }
}

public class MailNotification : INotification
{
    public MailNotification(string from, string userName, string password, MailboxAddress to, int port, string smtpServer)
    {

    }

    public Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string message, string content)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            try
            {
                client.Connect(smtpServer, port, true);
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                client.Authenticate(userName, password);
                emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(from));
                emailMessage.To.Add(to);
                emailMessage.Subject = subject;
                emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Text) { Text = content };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return OperationResult<string>.BuildFailure(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return OperationResult<string>.BuildSuccessResult("Success Send Email");
    }
}

public class ConsoleLoggingNotificationDecorator : INotification
{
    private readonly INotification _notification;
    public ConsoleLoggingNotificationDecorator(INotification notification) => _notification = notification;

    public Task<OperationResult<string>> Send(string message, string content)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Sending message in notification channel");
        var result = _notification.Send(message, content);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Message has completed send in notification channel");
        return result;
    }
}
```